# Permission issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, logins

I have restored one db of one instance from uat to anthother dev instance of the same server but how to fix orphan users I got 106  users how to fix and how to create logins is there any script for this scenario

Answer (score 1):

I've started using Powershell and dbatools - you can copy and migrate all kinds of sql objects (copying logins is super easy) - see this link - https://dbatools.io/getting-started/